# Taskbar Icons not staying on the lefthand side

Tags: taskbar

I'm using Windows 2016 and cannot get my icons on my taskbar to stay at the lefthand side of the taskbar - like previously on (I think) Windows 2007.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of it

Comment: Windows 2016? Windows 2007? Are you sure?